# Windows 7: create symbolic directory link from NAS to NAS

Tags: windows-7, mklink

T: is a NAS.  I want to have a symbolic link allowing me to choose which of several hierarchies is the "current version" of something.

I've tried the following as normal user:

```
C:>T:
T:>cd foo
T:\foo>mkdir bar2.0
T:\foo>mklink /D bar bar2.0
Access is denied
```

So I've found that creating symlinks isn't normally permissioned but can be done as superuser.

I start another MS-DOS window by right-clicking the MS-DOS icon and choosing "run as administrator."

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>T:
The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

So I've found that drive mappings are per-user not per-computer (didn't know that in 28 years of Windows usage!)  Solution:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net use T: \\myNAS\volume1\temp
C:\WINDOWS\system32>T:
T:>cd foo
T:\foo>mklink /D bar bar2.0
The request is not supported.
```

At this point I'm lost.  I've found similar questions on SuperUser, but a mysterious command tells me that "remote to remote" is disabled.  Does "remote" mean a mounted disk?

```
>fsutil behavior query SymLinkEvaluation
Local to local symbolic links are enabled.
Local to remote symbolic links are enabled.
Remote to local symbolic links are disabled.
Remote to remote symbolic links are disabled.
```

I've also tried logging into my Synology running 6.2.4 and going to that directory, and its gui doesn't have an obvious way to make a symlink.

I've logged to the Synology as user admin, and gone to that directory

```
admin@DiskStation:/volume1/temp/foo$ ln -s bar2.0 bar
admin@DiskStation:/volume1/temp/foo$ ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx+ 1 admin    users   11 Mar 22 12:12 bar-> bar2.0
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 myuser   users 4096 Mar 22 10:58 bar2.0
```

Then back on the PC, I now see `bar` is a directory... but if I try to `cd` to it I get `Access is denied.` despite the clear 777 permissioning visible on the SSH session shown above.  Interestingly, despite being visible in the SSH session and on the PC, the Synology's web-page-based desktop's File Station utility (much like a Windows Explorer) does *not* show the link `bar`.

I have a box I can reboot to Linux, and try making a symlink from Linux, but don't know if that's the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable remote to remote symbolic links, enter the following
command as Administrator:

```
fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation R2R:1
```

There is no response if the command was successful.

To enable both remote-to-local and remote-to-remote symbolic link
evaluations:

```
fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation R2R:1 R2L:1
```

To check that the setting has been updated, enter your query again:

```
fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation
```

For more information see the article
[Enable Symbolic Link Evaluations](https://helpcenter.netwrix.com/NA/996/Configure_IT_Infrastructure/File_Servers/Enable_Symlink.html).